# Do I always need to use mysql_fetch

Tags: php, mysql

I seem to always use these lines when i am doing a select in PHP

```
 $product_query = "Select ProductID from productinfo where PartName = '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[0])."'";
 $product_result = mysql_query($product_query) ;
 $product = mysql_fetch_assoc($product_result) ;
 $my_product_id = $product['ProductID'];
```

This works but it clutters the page so i was wondering if there an way to do this in a more concise manner

Comment: If it _'clutters the page'_, it's likely you aren't separating business logic & and presentation properly.

Comment: **Do not use mysql_* please. This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your own class which just returns the data after you give it the query.

```
$db = new Db;
$data = $db->query('blah');
print_r($data);
```

You can also use PDO, which has a similar, cleaner and safer API:

http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html